# Move Angular's dependencies to devDependencies

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've generated a project with the Angular CLI `ng new my-dream-app` and I've noticed that I get the following dependency structure in `package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.14",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.11",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Now imagine that I'm using the CLI generated project with a backend framework (e.g., expressjs) that handles static assets.
Furthermore, imagine that I want to deploy my app at some cloud service.

I can build locally the static assets and then move the entire project to the cloud where I would run `npm i --production` to install only the dependencies and then run `npm start`
However, I don't want to install any Angular-related libs at cloud. I only want to install strictly what's necessary to run my app (`express`, `body-parser`, `cookie-parser` etc.).

**Now the actual question**: will CLI still work properly if I manually move Angular's `dependencies` to `devDependencies`? Things like ng update? Would it move back some dependencies from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`? Would it create duplicate entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular CLI creates a `package.json` file that lists the packages needed at runtime in your Angular project under `dependencies`, and the packages needed to build it using the CLI under `devDependencies`. I wouldn't really recommend moving the `dependencies` to `devDependencies`, but I get the general idea of doing so since at runtime the packages are already packed into your app using Webpack.

To answer your question: To build Angular 2+ using the CLI you will definitely need Angular's core packages (such as `@angular/core`, `@angular/compiler-cli`, etc...) installed, so moving these packages to `devDependencies` and using `npm i --production` will make you unable to build your app. Therefore, I wouldn't recommend using `npm i --production` in your case.

What I can suggest is to use [`npm prune --production`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune.html) which will remove the packages specified in your `devDependencies` if you don't want them installed later on (e.g. after your build, if you're deploying your app). This is what my team does.

Also, to answer the last of your questions, `ng update` uses the `npm` CLI to install the packages; AFAIK, NPM doesn't allow duplicates in its `package.json`, so no worries.